# show christmas images based on date

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I want to be able to turn on and off code based on the dates of say Dec 15 and Dec 28, so that my images show up, and then go away. currently I am doing this:

```
<% If 1=2 Then %>
<p><!--#include file="include_files/holiday-include-Christmas.htm"--></p>
<% End If %>
```

and I have to change the `1=2` to a `1=1`. I want to have this done automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check the date:

```
<%
today   = Date
mindate = DateSerial(Year(today), 12, 15)
maxdate = DateSerial(Year(today), 12, 28)
If today >= mindate And today <= maxdate Then
%>
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly!! Will never have to worry again.  Now I have run in to a small glitch for the New Years Part.    I want the new years images to appear from 29 dec, to 5 jan. it was not working with 12,29     and 1,5, so i just duplicated it.                    
<% today   = Date
mindate = DateSerial(Year(today), 1, 1)
maxdate = DateSerial(Year(today), 1, 5)
If today >= mindate And today <= maxdate Then
%>

<p><center><!--#include file="include_files/holiday-include-New-Years.htm"--></center></p>
<% end if %>

Comment: You have a year change in that range, so you need a condition `If today >= mindate Or today <= maxdate Then`.